# Kotlin lambdas' return can always be stored as unit, not so for other functions

Tags: kotlin, lambda

Minimal example:

```
val clearlyOne: Unit = { 1 }()
println(clearlyOne)
```

Compiles and prints "Kotlin.Unit"

But

```
fun one() = 1
val clearlyOne2: Unit = one()
println(clearlyOne2)
```

And

```
val one = { 1 }
val clearlyOne3: Unit = one()
println(clearlyOne3)
```

Gives a Type Mismatch error at compile time.

What gives?

Comment: Lambdas are special. That's just how it works (and it makes practical use a lot easier). Consider the alternative: You'd have a lot of lambdas that look like `{ methodThatReturnsSomething(); Unit }`

Comment: @Bladt The return type of _fun one()_ is _Int_, not _Unit_.

Comment: @Bladt _fun one() = 1_ is short for _fun one(): Int { return 1 }_

Comment: @lukas.j I don't think that's the question. The question is "why can you assign the result of invoking a lambda *that also returns Int* to a variable of type `Unit`.

Comment: @Jorn: I understood the question differently, based on '... not so for other functions' and 'Gives a Type Mismatch error at compile time'. But you are probably right.

Comment: Both of your angles are relevant :)
So how about 
val one = {1}; val a: Unit = one()
That still type errors, so in this case the implicit unit return doesn't "take over"

Comment: But `val one: () -> Unit = { 1 }; val a: Unit = one()` does work. The magic is in the lambda signature, not in invoking it.

Comment: If the magic is in the signature, then I feel like
`val one = {1};
val a: Unit = one()` Should "work", i.e. compile and run, but it doesn't.
It seems specific to the "inline" use of lamdas

Comment: @Bladt But `{1}` is a lambda of type `() -> Int` and not of type `() -> Unit`. So it is like Jorn says.

Comment: Once the variable type is determined on the line where it is declared and assigned, it cannot be implicitly changed by the next line. The implications of such a feature would leave many confusing, ambiguous situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your understanding of this case is wrong. It doesn't work in the way that the value returned from a lambda is somehow converted/replaced from `Int` to `Unit`. It's actually the other way around: if the compiler sees we need a lambda returning `Unit`, it produces such lambda. This lambda never was of type: `() -> Int`. it is `() -> Unit` from the very beginning, because we needed a lambda returning `Unit`.

It works in a similar way as with lambda params. If we do `listOf(1, 2, 3).sumOf { it * it }`, then we never said what kind of lambda do we create, we never specified the number of arguments and their types. But the compiler "knew" that the `sumOf()` requires an `(Int) -> Int`, so it created exactly such lambda. If the compiler would know we need a lambda returning `Unit`, it would create one.

Explaining your examples:

- `fun one() = 1` - this function returns an `Int`, so you can't use it to return a `Unit`.
- `val one = { 1 }` - this is similar: we created a lambda returning `Int`, so we can't use it to return `Unit`.
- `val clearlyOne: Unit = { 1 }()` - this is different: the compiler sees we need a lambda returning `Unit`, so it creates one. This is similar to passing a lambda to a function which requires `() -> Unit`.

Please note the type inference for lambdas doesn't work across multiple lines of code. If we create a lambda for `sumOf()` in another line, we have to specify the type of its arguments explicitly. Similarly, to produce a lambda returning `Unit`, the compiler has to know the return type at the line where the lambda is defined.

Comment: 100% this. I missed the fact that the return type of a lambda may be inferred from (very local) context